ggplot is making a large gap between months on x-axis
I am making several plots by season, and I have no issues making figures with my code below for consecutive months (3 months at a time), until I get to winter. Because I want to plot values for Dec, Jan, Feb my figure gets messed up since the x-axis scale wants to remain from Jan-Dec. It is making a long line between the data points in Feb all the way to Dec.
How do I edit my code so that it still plots winter's 3 months evenly spaced out? I don't mind if it goes from Jan, Feb, Dec but ideally would like it to be Dec, Jan, Feb just to show it consecutively (and so it can match up with my other figures).
ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(data=y2020, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., color="2020"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(data=y2020, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., color="2020"), size=2) +
  geom_line(data=y2021, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., colour="2021"), linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(data=y2021, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., color="2021"), size=2) +
  geom_line(data=y2022, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., colour="2022"),linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(data=y2022, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., color="2022"), size=2) +
  geom_line(data=y2023, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., colour="2023"),linewidth=1) +
  geom_point(data=y2023, aes(x=Month, y=Max.Temp..C., color="2023"), size=2) +
  ggtitle("Max Temp - Winter (TCC)") +      
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35), limits=c(-15,35)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1:12), labels=month.abb[1:12]) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, colour="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, colour="black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
        legend.text = element_text(size=15),
        legend.title = element_text(size=15)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels=c("2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "30-Year Avg"), 
        values=c("#A6CEE3","#B2DF8A","#FB9A99","#FDBF6F", "black")) +
  ylab(expression(atop('Average Max Temperature   '^o*C), "\n")) +
  labs(color="Year") + xlab("\nMonth") 


structure(list(Longitude..x. = c(-79.4, -79.4, -79.4, -79.4, 
-79.4, -79.4, -79.4, -79.4, -79.4, -79.4, -79.4, -79.4), Latitude..y. = c(43.63, 
43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 43.63, 
43.63, 43.63), Station.Name = c("TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", 
"TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", 
"TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", 
"TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", "TORONTO CITY CENTRE", 
"TORONTO CITY CENTRE"), Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 2023L), Month = c(1L, 
2L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 12L), Max.Temp..C. = c(2.19, 
1.02, 3.3, 1.05, -0.6, 5.13, -1.91, 0.53, 3.01, 2.2, 3.44, 5.5
), Min.Temp..C. = c(-3.37, -4.81, -1.89, -3.77, -6.51, -0.32, 
-10.92, -6.7, -1.89, -2.09, -4.35, 1.25), Mean.Temp..C. = c(-0.6, 
-1.9, 0.7, -1.4, -3.6, 2.4, -6.4, -3.1, 0.6, 0.1, -0.5, 3.4), 
    Total.Precip..mm. = c(4.07, 0.94, 1.48, 0.81, 0.74, 1.59, 
    0.66, 2.08, 3.11, 1.93, 1.59, 2.19)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 48L), class = "data.frame")


Whereas with my code above, I have nice figures for other seasons such as spring:


You could try something like this where you treat the months as factors and set the levels however you want them!
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)



examp_data = examp_data |> 
  mutate(month = case_when(
    Month == 1 ~ "January",
    Month == 2 ~ "February",
    Month == 12 ~ "December"
  ),
  month = factor(month, levels = c("December", "January", "February")),
  year = factor(Year, levels  = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)))
  


ggplot(examp_data, aes(x = month, y = Max.Temp..C., color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35), limits=c(-15,35)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=15, colour="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, colour="black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size=15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=15),
        legend.text = element_text(size=15),
        legend.title = element_text(size=15)) +
  scale_color_manual(labels=c("2020", "2021", "2022", "2023", "30-Year Avg"), 
                     values=c("#A6CEE3","#B2DF8A","#FB9A99","#FDBF6F", "black")) +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-06-27 with reprex v2.1.0
UPDATE: If you have all the months you could do something like this
levels_fct = c("December", "January", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November")

examp_data = examp_data |> 
  mutate(month = case_match(Month
     1 ~ "January",
     2 ~ "February",
     3 ~ "March", 
     4 ~ "April",
     5 ~ "May", 
     6 ~ "June",
     7 ~ "June",
     8 ~ "August", 
     9 ~ "September",
     10 ~ "October",
     11 ~ "November",
     12 ~ "December",
  ),
  month = factor(month, levels = levels_fct),
  seasons = case_when(month %in% c("January", "February", "December")~ "Winter",
                     month %in% c("March", "April", "May") ~ "Spring",
                    month %in% c("June", "July", "August") ~ "Summer",
                month %in% c("September", "October", "November" ~ "Fall")),
  year = factor(Year, levels  = c(2020, 2021, 2022, 2023)))


Then if you wanted you could make plots for each season individually
ggplot(data = filter(examp_data, season == "Spring",
  aes(x = month, y = Max.Temp..C., color = year, group = year)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    geom_line(linewidth = 1) 


## or just facet by season 

ggplot(examp_data, aes(x = month, y = Max.Temp..C., color = year, group = year)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
facet_wrap(vars(season))




This isn't working for me because it's creating a category of "NA" for all the other months.

Ahh I see. I'll add an update

I've tried this again and after fixing 7 ~ July I am still getting a weird error that I don't understand:
Error in `mutate()`: ℹ In argument: `month = factor(month, levels = levels_fct)`. Caused by error in `levels<-`: ! factor level [8] is duplicated Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.  But nothing is duplicated...

In this case, I accidentally added July twice

Right, so I had fixed it but it still shows the error.

Actually my bad the error is different. After fixing the July in levels_fct and removing the duplicate June, this is the error:
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: seasons = case_when(...).
Caused by error in `case_when()`: ! Case 4 (`month %in% c("September", "October", "November" ~ "Fall")`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector. Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

case_match does not need the == part. Just to confirm you also fixed the levels_fct vector? I accidentally included July twice in that too and that is what that error is is telling you

Yes I fixed those. I found the error. This part of the code month %in% c("September", "October", "November" ~ "Fall")), but the bracket needed to be before the ~ portion so it would be month %in% c("September", "October", "November") ~ "Fall"). Going to see if the figures work now!

Yea it's not working I can't create the figures. The filter is causing an error.
Error in `filter()`: ℹ In argument: `aes(x = month, y = Max.Temp..C., color = year, group = year)`. Caused by error in `vec_size()`: ! `x` must be a vector, not a <uneval> object.

Oh it worked~ Don't know why, I just had to restart R and I guess it was fine. Thanks for your help!

Glad it finally worked out!
